# How to add/remove or show/hide textbox in an Angular form according to dropdown value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9, angular-template-form

[image: r]

On selecting a particular item from this open dropdown I want the textboxes to be shown in the form
Each of these dropdown value has certain properties which are being fetched from database.

**This is the form**

```
    <mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
                <mat-label>Item Group Name</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="model.itemGroupId" name="itemGroupId" #itemGroup="ngModel" 
     (selectionChange)="getGroupDetail()" required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let group of model.itemGroupList" 
      [value]="group.ItemGroupId">
                        {{ group.ItemGroupName }}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                <mat-error *ngIf="itemGroup.invalid && itemGroup.touched">Select an Item Group</mat- 
        error>
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <mat-form-field class="col-md-6" *ngIf="model.maintenanceSchedule">
                <mat-label>Maintainance Schedule(Days)</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="model.strMaintenanceSchedule" 
         name="strMaintenanceSchedule" #maintenance="ngModel" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="maintenance.invalid && maintenance.touched">Maintenance Schedule is 
            Required</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="col-md-6" *ngIf="model.calibrationSchedule">
                <mat-label>Callibration Schedule(Days)</mat-label>
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="model.strCalibrationSchedule" 
        name="strCalibrationSchedule" #calibration="ngModel" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="calibration.invalid && calibration.touched">Calibration Schedule is 
      Required</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**Method I'm calling on selection of dropdown item**

```
    getGroupDetail(){
        this.service.getItemGroupDetail(this.model.itemGroupId).subscribe((res:any)=>{
            if(res.isIdentityExist==true){
                if(res.isSuccess ==true){
                    this.model.itemGroupList=res.itemGroup;
                    this.model.maintenanceSchedule=res.itemGroup.MaintenanceSchedule==true? 
      true:false;
                    this.model.calibrationSchedule=res.itemGroup.CalibrationSchedule==true? 
         true:false;
                }
                else{
                    this.toast.error(res.responseMsg);
                }
            }
            else{
                this.toast.error(res.responseMsg);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.router.navigate(["./login"]);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
     }
```

I Want to keep the textboxes hidden when the dialog opens . and only show the maintenance textBox when maintainanceSchedule is true and calibration textbox when the calibrationSchedule is true or both if both true in the getGroupDetail() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you should be using the **Reactive Form** approach instead of the **Template Driven** solution that you have in place.
Basically instead of using `[(ngModel)]` you switch to using `FormControl's` and possibly the `FormBuilder`. There is a good comparison of the two approaches here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/difference-between-template-driven-and-reactive-forms-angular

The Angular docs itself offer a great guide to using **Reactive Forms** to create dynamically generated forms that can show/hide fields based on other fields values and more. You can find the guide here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: is it not possible at all in this approach?

Comment: doing it dynamically (as I understand is what you are doing, because you are fetching the fields from the database) will be a huge pain.
if you know which fields to show for every selected value, you can add them to the template and use `*ngIf` to show or hide them

Comment: then please suggest how to do it using reactive form?

Comment: After using the reactive form I was able to do it , but there's a problem ,If a textbox is shown on a dropdown change event it is a required field so validation message is shown left blank. Now in this state  if I change to some other dropdown value the textbox disappears and when it re-appears again it comes with the error message and red colored

Comment: Please open another question with some code for this

Comment: Thanks I implemented it perfectly after using reactive form as you had suggested.